# seamless dynamic plugin loading

Tags: python, plugins, dynamic, module, namespaces

I'm working on an extensible plugin subsystem for a framework, but I'm stuck on how to get the system to dynamically and seamlessly load plugins from within the plugins themselves.  I already know how to add the plugins (probably going to use entry-points). As an example:

pluga.py

```
from framework.plug_lib import plugin

@plugin
def foo():
    return 2

@plugin
def bar():
    return foo()
```

plugb.py

```
from framework.plug_lib import plugin

@plugin
def foo():
    return 3
```

framework.plug_lib.py

```
loaded_plugins = {}

class Plugin(object):
    def __init__(self, plug): #note plug could be class, function, method, etc
        self.plug = plug
    def plug_load(self):
        loaded_plugins[self.plug.__name__] = self.plug
    def plug_get_loaded_version(self):
        try:
            return loaded_plugins[self.plug.__name__]
        except KeyError:
            raise RuntimeError('No plugin %s loaded.' % self.plug.__name__)

def plugin(plug):
    return Plugin(plug)

def load(plugin_path):
    # get plugin by searching entry-points, other basic logic
    plugin.plug_load()
```

Usage examples:

```
from framework.plug_lib import load, loaded_plugins

load('pluga.foo')
load('pluga.bar')
loaded_plugins['bar']() # 2
```

.

```
from framework.plug_lib import load, loaded_plugins

load('plugb.foo')
load('pluga.bar')
loaded_plugins['bar']() # 3
```

This is simplified to try to illustrate the problem concisely.  In the real framework, there are multiple different types of plugins, and they all go to different `loaded_plugin` analogs.  If the container for the plugins was a class, I could probably figure a way to shoehorn this in to a descriptor or something, but part of the point of this is to refactor out some boilerplate code that wraps the plugins currently.  Can I customize the way the module itself inspects it's own namespace and retrieves it's members with no or at most only a single simple line in the plugin module itself?  I basically need something equivalent to `__getattribute__` on the module itself so I can make `Plugins` behave like poor man's descriptors and return `self.plug_get_loaded_version()` whenever an attempt is made to access anything other than their `plug_load()` method, I think, but I have no idea how to do that.  Maybe package-time code (something in setup.py), but I think then you wouldn't be able to work on the installed packages in develop mode without rebuilding every time.  Any ideas out there?

Comment: So I had an idea... I'm going to try giving `Plugin` a `__call__()` that calls `self.plug`, and making `Plugin` a metaclass so that when you inherit from a `Plugin` object, it will substitute in `self.plug_loaded_version()` at runtime.